# Bonus Actions Are Actions? Combining Two Weapon Fighting and Extra Attack (Newly Expanded)

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, two-weapon-fighting, multiattack, bonus-action

Let me first start by clarifying, I believe there is a point that has been missed in this question before. Consider that before marking it a repeat:

**What is the precise differentiation between a bonus action and an action?**

I believe that the combination of two weapon fighting and Extra Attack (granted at Level 5 Paladin) allows for a total of 4 attacks. Can anyone confirm this? Let me outline.

Extra attack: "Beginning at 5th Level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn."

Two Weapon Fighting: "...you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon...".

Most answers I've seen say three attacks, i.e. You get the Attack Action, which includes 2 attacks, and the bonus Action which includes 1 attack.

However, I believe the correct breakdown is first to thinking You get the Attack Action, which grants a Bonus Action (Attack Action). Now both of these Attack Actions should benefit from Extra Attack, giving 4 (lower case a) attacks within 2 (upper case A) Attack Actions. Thoughts?

The rules seem clear, that a bonus action is an action. And an action used to attack is an attack action. Thus, a bonus action used to attack is an attack action.

**If this is not the case, where is there a clear distinction between bonus action and action?**

Comment: That's not correct, that requires 10 rep to answer. Also, if you re-read my breakdown, there is only one Bonus Action. That bonus action has two attacks. It's important to note than an attack (lower case a) is not an Action. In my example, each Action (initial and bonus) has two attacks.

Comment: It's *really* hard for me to understand how this isn't fundamentally an attempted competing answer at some other "how many attacks?" question. That said, you've asked some specific questions and gotten at least one answer, so I'm inclined to leave it be. I've also unprotected the Q&A that medix2 linked so that you can submit your competing interpretation there, if you like. Happy gaming!

Comment: This very much seems like a duplicate of something, but it's unclear exactly what the question is here. Are you asking how many attacks a paladin with two weapon fighting gets after 5th level? Or are you asking asking about the difference between the Attack action vs just an attack? Or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? If the RAW, then this is a duplicate. If "how it should be"/"the fun way to play", then this is opinion based, but could be rephrased as "what would the implications or consequences be?".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many attacks can a fighter with two-weapon fighting make at 5th level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55587/how-many-attacks-can-a-fighter-with-two-weapon-fighting-make-at-5th-level)

Comment: I've removed my earlier comments and am posting this so that new answerers might see it: Please support, using textual evidence, why a bonus action that involves an attack either is or it not considered to be the Attack action. This is, as I understand it, the crux of the question here

Answer (score 7):

## A Bonus Action attack is **not** an Attack Action.

The [Player's Handbook, Ch 9](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#ActionsinCombat) talks about the actions you can take during the Action portion of your turn. One of those actions is the Attack Action.

According to [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#TwoWeaponFighting)

> When you take the Attack action...you can use a **bonus action to attack**....
>
> If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon, instead of making **a melee attack** with it.

So, when you take the Attack Action, you can use a Bonus Action to attack and make **"a melee attack"**. Regardless of how many attacks you get when you take the Attack Action, you only get the one, single melee attack as a Bonus Action.

---

But, just to be extra sure, let's take a look at Bonus Actions themselves. Under the [*Your Turn*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#YourTurn) section of the Player's Handbook (Ch 9) there are rules for how Bonus Actions work.

> You can take a bonus action **only** when a special ability, spell, or
> other feature of the game states that you can do something as a bonus
> action. *You otherwise don't have a bonus action to take.*
>
> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose
> which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

Whenever a Bonus Action allows you to do something that is typically an Action, it specifically says *what* and *how* you can do it.

- For instance, the Rogue class feature [*Cunning Action*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#ClassFeatures) allows a Rogue to:

> ...take a bonus action on each of your turns in combat. This action
> can be used **only** to take the Dash, Disengage, or Hide action.

- Another example is the Cleric's [*Healing Word*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-word) spell. Spell casting typically requires the Cast a Spell Action, yet here we have a spell with a cast time of a Bonus Action. Does that mean you can take the Cast a Spell Action to cast what ever you want and cast *Healing Word* as well?? No. According to the [Spellcasting rules (PHB,Ch 10)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#BonusAction) when you want to cast a spell with a cast time of 1 Bonus Action:

> You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided
> that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. *You can't
> cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a
> casting time of 1 action.*

Neither of the examples above are attacks. Since there are a variety of Bonus Actions available in the game, a Bonus Action is **not** automatically related to an attack.

Finally, you are *not* getting an Action as a bonus *(small 'b')*, but are instead triggering a Bonus Action which is its own *unique entity* and is not part of the normal action economy. Special game mechanics *give* you a Bonus Action which you can only use for specific purposes, you don't *use* a Bonus Action to take the Attack Action.

So, while I can aaaaaalmost see your logic, the rules clearly say that a Bonus Action gives **an** attack, *not* an Attack Action.