# Do bonus actions trigger the save from an Internal Injury?

Tags: dnd-5e, optional-rules, injury, bonus-action

One of the possible injuries from the optional "Lingering Injuries" table in the DMG is Internal Injury:

> **Internal Injury.** Whenever you attempt an action in combat, you must make a DC 15 Constitution saving throw. On a failed save, you lose your action and can't use reactions until the start of your next turn. The injury heals if you receive magical healing or if you spend ten days doing nothing but resting.

When suffering from an Internal Injury, do you have to make this saving throw when attempting a bonus action in combat, or just when attempting normal actions?

Comment: Related: "[Are bonus actions and actions interchangeable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111389)" and "[Bonus Actions Are Actions? Combining Two Weapon Fighting and Extra Attack \(Newly Expanded\)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169063)" and "[Can you ready a bonus action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152204)"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, because a bonus action is an action

The rules for [bonus actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions) state that a bonus action is a special kind of action:

> Various class features, spells, and other abilities let you take an additional action on your turn called a bonus action

Further, in the [SA Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf), on page 7 you can find the Q/A:

> **Does using a bonus action break invisibility from a warlock’s One with Shadows invocation?**
>
> Taking a bonus action breaks the invisibility of a warlock’s One with Shadows. A bonus action is an action.

For comparison, the wording of [One With Shadows](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) in this question is:

> When you are in an area of dim light or darkness, you can use your action to become invisible until you move or take an action or a reaction.

This suggests that indeed a bonus action is considered an action and so Internal Injury would also trigger when attempting to take a bonus action.

Comment: If I understand this correctly "your action" does *not* include bonus actions whereas "an action" does?

Comment: @Medix2 that's a good catch, Internal Injury does say you lose "your action" which usually means the "normal" action that you can take on a turn (such as in my example One With Shadows"). So in this case we probably need to apply the associated context to interpret "your action" as "the action you were trying to take". Not entirely happy with this, though, it really is a weirdly worded feature

Comment: I meant the "your action" in the One With Shadows feature refers exclusively to the regular non-bonus action, whereas the "an action" in that same feature refers to both the regular action *and* bonus actions. That's at least how I understand the argument being made

Comment: @Medix2 well yes in that feature that seems pretty clear, given the Sage Advice