# Does Thirsting Blade Stack With Twinned Blades?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, two-weapon-fighting, eldritch-invocations, multiattack

Does Twinned Blades from the [*Compendium of Forgotten Secrets: Awakening*](https://www.genfantasypress.com/about-the-compendium) stack with Thirsting Blade? Twinned Blades says both weapons are pact weapons, and Thirsting Blade affects my pact weapon. So can I make  4 attacks in a turn with these two invocations using plus 1 from Improved Pact Weapon and add my Strength Modifier to both attacks?

Here are the Twinned Blades Invocation from *Compendium of Forgotten Secrets: Awakening* and Thirsting Blade:

> **TWINNED BLADES**
>
> *Prerequisite: Pact of the Blade feature*
>
> You gain access to a second pact weapon, and you can summon both whenever you would summon one of them. When you engage in two-weapon fighting using both your pact weapons, you can add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack.

> **THIRSTING BLADE**
>
> *Prerequisite: 5th level, Pact of the Blade feature*
>
> You can attack with your pact weapon twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

Comment: Related: "[How many attacks can a fighter with two-weapon fighting make at 5th level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55587)"

Answer (score 12):

#### You would get three attacks total because Twinned Blades uses Two-Weapon Fighting and *not* the Attack action itself

What Thirsting Blade does, is it allows you to attack twice with your Pact Weapon *when you take the Attack action*. [You are only taking *one* Attack action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55589), so you only get the extra attack *once*.

What Twinned Blades lets you do is use Two-Weapon Fighting *while adding a damage modifier*. To quote [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting):

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand. You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative. [...]

Two-Weapon Fighting involves *making an attack* but it does not involve the Attack *action* itself (for more on this distinction, we have: "[What does upper-case-A-Attack action vs. lower-case-a-attack mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105781)"). Because the Twinned Blades Eldritch Invocation does *not* allow you to take a second Attack action, you cannot benefit from Thirsting Blade a second time. This gives you a grand total of three attacks (one from the Attack action, one from Thirsting Blade, and one from Two-Weapon Fighting).

Comment: Just as a small additional point, even if Twinned Blades EI DID give you a SECOND Attack Action (similar to the Fighter's Action Surge), that still would not give you access to a second Bonus Action.

Comment: @goodguy In that scenario it *would* be five attacks instead of three (Attack action, Thirsting, Attack action, Thirsting, TWF)

Comment: I agree, but your last sentence reads like "and if you got a second action, you could used twinned blade again", at least to me. Just picking nits